# Selenium 2 with PHPUnit function byLinkText()

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing

Okey, So i am trying to run a selenium test case using PHPUnit.
I did a lot of little test using  or checkbox etc.. but i have a problem that i thought easy..

I just want to go to the other page using the function byLinkText("Text of link") 
So, at first sight it's not hard but it's doesn't work and i don't know why..

This is my html :

```
<div id="menu-haut">
    <ul class="ul0">
        <li class="li0"><a href="/order" class="lien0">Commander</a></li>
        <li class="li0"><a href="/gerer" class="lien0">Gérer</a></li>
        <li class="li0"><a href="#" class="lien0 inactive">Analyser</a></li>
        <li class="li0"><a href="#" class="lien0 inactive">Services</a></li>
        <li class="li0 active0"><a href="/support" class="lien0active">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So,i just want to click on the 'Support' link.
Logically i will do with Selenium 2 :

```
$this->byLinkText('Support')->click();
```

but it's doesn't work and i have this error :

```
1) BoitierTest::testLink
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Support"}
```

if someone can explian me this sh.. ^^ I would be grateful

Comment: Ist that method working on other links? Are you sure that the page is fully loaded when you call the method? What result yields a call to `byPartialLinkText("Support")` instead?

Comment: Yes the page is fully loaded when i call the method. i wrote this : $this->timeouts()->implicitWait(5000); to be sur that the page is loaded correctly. I tried "byPartialLinkText" and the result is same.. However "byLinkText" means that its mean , so i don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem.
In fact, , as i resumed the code, and there was an css attribute which makes everything not working.

The attribute was : text-transform : uppercase;

and despite this , in the source code, it's was write 'Support' and in my interface 'SUPPORT' so i removed it , and it's works well now.